# How to preselect Windows display DPI for Active Directory account?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I'm using an Active Directory account to manage 10~20 servers. Whenever I setup a new server and login to a new server for the first time, the first thing I do is to right-click on the desktop, go to the Display settings and set the DPI scaling to 125%.

This step is extremely annoying for the number of servers I need to access. How can I either:

1. Set the DPI to 125% for all machines for the specific Active Directory account? OR,
2. Set the DPI to 125% for all new user profiles for all future new servers? (I guess I can configure something then `sysprep`?)

Comment: And the first thing I do is curse and set it back to 100%. It's extremely annoying when all the text is fuzzy and the wrong size. Think more in terms of a _user_ setting than a _device_ setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a group policy, which targets users. You can set SOM - AD group, where you'll be the only member. The first post in [this technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/c20c4c47-092d-4daa-b4a8-154b3852e13d/using-group-policy-to-set-windows-font-dpi-size) contains detailed steps on how to set it up.

1. Create an OU for the users.
2. Link a GPO to this OU.
3. Under User Configuration / Preferences / Registry, select NEW / Registry Wizard.
4. Set the DWORD `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels` as:

   - 00000060 for 100%
   - 00000090 for 125%
   - 00000144 for 150%